# set cookie on parent domain but from sub-domain website

Tags: javascript

When I visit a sub-domain website ex: https://sub2.example.com,  from a browser console I can set a cookie for parent domain.

```
document.cookie = "nameCookie=HelloWorld; domain=.example.com;"
```

as per Cookie RFC this works!  and this cookie should be available to all sub-domains.
ex:

- https://example.com
- https://sub2.example.com
- https://xxx.example.com

But my problem,  this concept is not working on some websites.

for ex:

- Go to https://square.github.io/
- open browser console

  ```
  document.cookie = "nameCookie=HelloWorld; domain=.github.io;"
  console.log(document.cookie)
  ```

check that **nameCookie** is not available.

Why it is not working here? any Http header/rule setup on those websites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `github.io` is on [the list of *effective* top-level domains (eTLDs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Suffix_List) (raw list [here](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat)), so each `github.io` subdomain is treated like a subdomain of a top-level domain (that is, `_______.github.io` is treated just like `_______.com` or `_______.co.uk`).